# How Do I properly Encode `extra` parameters while using `airflow connections add`

Tags: airflow, airflow-connections

## Problem Statement

When editing the UI I can add modify the extra field to contain `{"no_host_key_check": true}`
[image]

But when I attempt to add this connection from the CLI with this command which follows [the connections documentation format](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html)

```
airflow connections add local_sftp --conn-uri "sftp://test_user:test_pass@local_spark_sftp_server_1:22/schema?extra='{\"no_host_key_check\": true}"
```

The connection is added as `{"extra": "'{\"no_host_key_check\": true}"}`
[image]

How do I need to modify my `airflow connections add` command to properly format this connection configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally a misunderstanding that all schema parameters for the `airflow connections add` command are extra parameters by default

```
airflow connections add local_sftp --conn-uri "sftp://test_user:test_pass@local_spark_sftp_server_1:22/schema?no_host_key_check=true"
```

Correctly sets the desired parameter.